# How to get bounds of current map view?

Tags: react-native, mapkit

How do I automatically get the bounds of the current map view? I've been looking everywhere. The Google Maps API has it: http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/ref_getbounds.asp

It would be nice to do it for React Native

Answer (score 0):

If you want it then you can have one extension for the **MKMapView** as below.

```
extension MKMapView {
    func getBounds() -> (southWestPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D, northEastPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let visibleMapRect = self.visibleMapRect
        let neMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(visibleMapRect), visibleMapRect.origin.y)
        let swMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(visibleMapRect.origin.x, MKMapRectGetMaxY(visibleMapRect))
        return (southWestPoint: MKCoordinateForMapPoint(swMapPoint), northEastPoint:MKCoordinateForMapPoint(neMapPoint))
    }
}
```

Whenever you want the bound just call the **getBounds** method.